# How to use babel to transform es6 to es5 programmatically?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a function which runs string as javascript code through `eval()`. It works fine if the string is `es5` but doesn't work for `es6`. I know babel can transport es6 to es5 but most of them use cases are done in compile stage. How can I use babel programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Babel has an API](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/).

I assume you can do something like this:

```
eval(babel.transform(code, options).code)
```

However I would strongly reconsider that! First, `eval` is usually a very, very dangerous thing, and next babel is huge. You don't want to deliver that to a browser if you don't have to.